# Insert the name in columns from stprl

Tags: r

From this process:

```
x = data.frame(id = c(1,2), col1 = c("text---here","text---there"))
levels = unique(unlist(strsplit(x$col1, split = "---")))
x = cbind(x, matrix(ncol = length(levels), nrow = nrow(x)))
for(i in 1:length(levels))
{
  x[,ncol(x)-length(levels)+i] <- as.numeric(grepl(levels[i], x$col1, fixed = TRUE))
}
```

How is it possible to insert the names of text which separate by --- instead of having number in column name

Expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c(1,1), here = c(1,0), there = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% 
  mutate(value = 1L) %>% 
  separate_rows(col1, sep = "---") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "col1", values_fill = 0L)
```

Output

```
 A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id  text  here there
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     0
2     2     1     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea if I use a different separator like this `?????` why I receive this error `Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)`

Comment: That `sep` has to be a valid regular expression. If you want literal a `?`, then it has to be escaped like this `\\?`. For more than one `?`, use `\\?+`.

Comment: Thank you again unfortunately I receive this `Error in values_fill[[value]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Perhaps update your question to show me what your real data looks like?